# File transfer software, linux, windows and apple

Tags: windows, linux, ios, file-synchronization, data-transfer

All

My goal is to send some image files, from a linux machine to a range of device, mostly laptops and phones. I was initially looking at wifi-direct but that is not supported by apple but then I came across something called Bonjour.

I have done some reading about it but I am still a little unclear as to what it is/can do.

If I want to send this photo from the linux machine to a companion app on any of these devices (laptops and phones) is Bonjour something I should be looking at or does anyone know of something that would be better

Thanks

EDIT/update

I have decided to axe apple from my project because who really wants to deal with their proprietary hardware. Instead I am going to use wifi-direct to interface with android devices because that is actually really easy, and then I will look into getting something working for Windows

Comment: Why not simply using [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) or [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/)?

Comment: I would but this system needs to work in places that may or may not have internet access

Comment: Well, no network means using a pen drive.

Comment: I suppose, but that is quite inconvenient. Im thinking I may have to use bluetooth

Comment: I never found a good working bluetooth file transfer solution. Let me know if you do.

Comment: If I do get this working I'll post it as an answer, thank for your help though

Comment: @MSC: network and internet are 2 different things!

Comment: @GarethShepherd: somehow related: https://superuser.com/q/653389 and https://superuser.com/q/517943

Comment: Maybe the WiFi plugin for Total Commander helps? It's available for Android, don't know about other OS http://www.ghisler.com/androidplugins/wifi/ . IMO, Total Commander runs on Linux and Windows, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dukto R6](http://www.msec.it/blog/?page_id=11) for your wireless **OR** wired (LAN) file transfer from a range of devices.

Available for Windows, Mac, Linux and Android (didn't work well with Android 7.0).

For Docs and Installation Process, Go to the above link.

Well from my experience, I have installed it on my Dell Inspiron laptop which is running with Ubuntu 16.04 and in my Asus Zenfone Max (Android Smartphone).

I connect my laptop to the hotspot created in my Smartphone and use Dukto for wireless file transfer.

If you liked this software, make some donation to support.

EDITED :

It will also work on LAN Connection

Answer (score 0):

Install a document management system such as [Nuxeo](https://www.nuxeo.com/downloads/) or [Alfresco community edition](https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/tags#/?tags=early%20access%20releases) on a server somewhere else and use it to host your documents. You can then download your documents from any OS that has a browser or even mount alfresco (not sure about Nuxeo) via webdav a system directory/drive (if you're of the windows lot)